# Can't get the main links hover focus to stay

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that I can't get my navigation links focused. When you try to click the link the it doesn't stay focused so the dropdown box only gets displayed for a second.
[This is the navigation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPO9HJjUktk&list=LLvvM0hd8ssgR9Mv0QJngxWg&index=4) I am trying to do.

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;}
header,nav,article,section,footer,aside {
display: block;}
#container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;}

.nav-main {
width: 100%;
background-color: #222;
height: 70px;
color: #fff;}
.logo {
float: left;
height: 40px;
padding: 15px 30px;
font-size: 1.4em;
line-height:40px;}
.nav-main > ul {
float: left;}
.nav-main > ul > li {
float: left;}
.nav-item:hover {
background-color: #444;}
.nav-item {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;}
.sub-link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;}
.nav-content {
position: absolute;
background-color: #444;
height: 200px;
max-height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;}
.nav-content-sub {
padding: 20px;}
.nav-content a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;}
.sub-link {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
line-height: 10px;}
.nav-item:focus {
background-color: #444;}
.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
max-height: 200px;}

        <nav class="nav-main">
        <div class="logo">Website</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="nav-item">News</a>
                <div class="nav-content">
                    <div class="nav-content-sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">Safsafasf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">Safsasagsagasg</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">Qgagsag</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">wKgagsagsagsgsagsaga<a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: Please use a proper style of displaying your code in the question, add the css seperate from the html or put your css in a style block in your html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give the `<a href="" class="nav-item">News</a>` a direction (link to a website or page). If you don't want the news item link to a page use `"#"` instead of `""` like so `<a href="#" class="nav-item">News</a>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;}
header,nav,article,section,footer,aside {
display: block;}
#container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;}

.nav-main {
width: 100%;
background-color: #222;
height: 70px;
color: #fff;}
.logo {
float: left;
height: 40px;
padding: 15px 30px;
font-size: 1.4em;
line-height:40px;}
.nav-main > ul {
float: left;}
.nav-main > ul > li {
float: left;}
.nav-item:hover {
background-color: #444;}
.nav-item {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;}
.sub-link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;}
.nav-content {
position: absolute;
background-color: #444;
height: 200px;
max-height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;}
.nav-content-sub {
padding: 20px;}
.nav-content a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;}
.sub-link {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
line-height: 10px;}
.nav-item:focus {
background-color: #444;}
.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
max-height: 200px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <nav class="nav-main">
        <div class="logo">Website</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item">News</a>
                <div class="nav-content">
                    <div class="nav-content-sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">Safsafasf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">Safsasagsagasg</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">Qgagsag</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" class="sub-link">wKgagsagsagsgsagsaga<a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
           </nav>
</body>
</html>
```